# Input bias current calculation

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, transimpedance

[image: VBP104FAS]

I have a VBP104FAS connected as above with the LMP7721 opamp to produce an output voltage from the photodiode's small input current. I am trying to calculate the input bias current I need as I am currently looking for a different opamp. From my understanding, the input bias current is the average current of the two inputs to the opamp.

Because the positive input is pulled down to GND, does this mean the input bias current is half of the typical reverse light current of the VBP104FAS (datasheet: https://www.vishay.com/docs/81169/vbp104fa.pdf) so it would be 35uA / 2 = 17.5uA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bias current is an inherent characteristic of the op-amp, and largely doesn't depend on what is attached to the op-amp. I.e. the photodiode application doesn't change anything here.

When the op-amp input is biased for correct operation, i.e. the op-amp is not saturated, there will be a bias current.

- For op-amps with NPN input stages, the bias current flows *into* each input.
- For op-amps with PNP input stages, the bias current flows *out of* each input.
- For rail-to-rail input bipolar op-amps with complementary (NPN+PNP) input stages, the bias current changes direction as the common mode voltage crosses a certain threshold region. To minimize bias drift-induced errors, it's recommended to operate the op-amp outside of this common mode transition range.
- For bipolar input op-amps with bias current cancellation, the bias current will have a bidirectional (+/-) specified maximum.
- For op-amps with JFET and MOS inputs, the bias current is small and may have a fixed polarity or arbitrary polarity.

  If the datasheet maximum is given as "+/-", then the current can have either polarity. Otherwise, the datasheet maximum will be either implicitly positive (out of the pin) or negative (into the pin).

Apart from the complementary bipolar input stage case, the bias current doesn't depend much on the input voltage, and is part- and temperature-dependent.

In the case of the transconductance amplifier like you got for the photodiode, the bias current is a source of error. You'll need to determine how much the bias current changes with temperature, how noisy it is (given as the input current noise), and whether that's acceptable to your requirements when you compare it to the full-scale photodiode current in your application.

> From my understanding, the input bias current is the average current of the two inputs to the opamp.

It is independent for each op-amp input. The average value is of little use when the bias current is comparable to the offset current (the difference between effective bias currents).

> Because the positive input is pulled down to GND [...]

This only sets the common mode voltage. It's wise to bias this common mode a bit above ground, as you've done, so that if the op-amp's bias current happens to be positive - flowing out of the inverting input - the output won't saturate at 0V in low light conditions.

Your biggest concerns are:

- Temperature coefficient of the bias current - since that adds thermal drift to the DC value of the photocurrent.

  If your application is AC-coupled, e.g. a data receive circuit, then the bias current drift is not relevant as long as the common mode operating point will ensure that output doesn't saturate for worst-case bias current.
- Input current noise, since it's in series with the photocurrent. The input current noise gets effectively multiplied by Rf and appears on the output as if it was an additional source of input-referred voltage noise!

> Input bias current calculation

There's nothing to calculate. It's given as a maximum (and sometimes typical) specification in the datasheet.

Do not mistake the op-amp bias current with the photodiode dark current: they are both important, but entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

> Because the positive input is pulled down to GND, does this mean the input bias current is half of the typical reverse light current of the VBP104FAS

No- The bias current is averaged to cancel out the offset current.  So the bias current specified flows in/out of each terminal, +/- the offset current.